# $a_1=2$ and $a_{n+1}=2+\frac{1}{a_n}\implies |a_{n+1}-a_n|\leq\frac14|a_{n-1}-a_n|$

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

> Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ satisfy that $a_1=2$ and $a_{n+1}=2+\frac{1}{a_n}$. Show that
>   for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq 2$,
>   $$
> |a_{n+1}-a_n|\leq\frac14|a_{n-1}-a_n|
> $$

So I can show the base case to be true, but I can't see how to show the inductive step.

Comment: $a_n \geq 2$ and $a_{n+1} - a_n = \frac{a_{n-1} - a_n}{a_n a_{n-1}}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\forall i\in \mathbb{N} \qquad a_{i}=2+\frac{1}{a_{i-1}}\geq2$$
$$a_{n+1}=2+\frac{1}{a_n}...(1)$$
$$a_{n}=2+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}...(2)$$

Subtracting (2) fom (1),
$$ |a_n-a_{n-1}|=|\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{a_na_{n-1}}|=\frac{|a_n-a_{n-1}|}{|a_na_{n-1|}}\leq\frac{|a_n-a_{n-1}|}{2\times 2}=\frac{|a_n-a_{n-1}|}{4}$$